# string.maketrans - freezes my Python IDE (spyder) - Mac

Tags: string, python-2.7, spyder

I am using Spyder on Mac running python 2.7

I have used "string.maketrans" before i never faced issues.

but when i use the same i encountering a freeze issue where i have to force quit the "Spyder" IDE and could not recover.
Like to hear if there is something i doing incorrectly here.
My code-

```
import string
dig_its = string.digits;
translate_digits = string.maketrans(dig_its,len(dig_its)*' ')
```

(trying to replace all digits to space)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in Spyder 3.0, released a month and a half ago. Please update to that version.